# Advanced js bundling

Tags: magento2, javascript, bundle, optimization

I try to optimize the bundles of magento with the information from devdocs . I try to do it on Magento 2.2.6 but the main issue is that after generating the bundles I get an error from the customer-data regarding

> TypeError: $.cookieStorage is undefined; can't access its "setConf"
>   property

Did anyone had this error?

EDIT:
After some more investigation looks like this error comes from `jquery/jquery.storageapi.min` strange think is that only when trying to do it as suggested on Magento Devdocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html

Comment: check if merge js is on then it suggest to make enable only one at a time eigher bundling js or js merge.it would be create problem if both are enable at the same time.

Comment: @Zaheerabbas with js merge disabled is the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, main problem was that the guide in the devdocs has some mistakes in it. To fix this I had to find in my `build.js` `"jquery/jquery-migrate": ["jquery"` in the `shim` section and replace it with `"jquery/jquery-migrate": ["jquery", "jquery/jquery.cookie"]` so just adding `jquery.cookie` to the deps fixed it

Comment: hi vlad, did you succeed to do the buding on 2.2.6? because i saw that the documentation is only for 2.3 version

Comment: i tried to do the bunding on the same version but i have a lot of err

Comment: @AlinLupoiu I used the same documentation but I had to change a bit the settings in the JS. like I said in my answer above. What errors you get?

Comment: I get error after adding code from step 4 of part 2 of the guide. The code that should  configure requirejs to use bundles. After i rerun the r.js -o command i get `Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
    at maybeCallback (fs.js:128:9)`

Comment: @Vlad Patru, hi could you please share your skype so I can get your help in advanced JS bundling? The only issue is that all my advanced JS bundles load on the catalog page which should only load default and catalog.js bundles.